# How to use my laptop as server

Tags: android, gps

Am using GPS I want to insert longitude and latitude in database.in emulator it working fine am getting the value inserted in database, in mobile it is not working ,how to use my laptop as server.I want to insert longitude and latitude from mobile am using web services(Json).

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity
    {
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    Button btnShowLocation;
    GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                 latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                 String Text = "My current Latitude = " + latitude  + " Longitude = " + longitude;

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

                 SendQueryString();
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }



        }
         public void SendQueryString() {
                new Thread() {  
                    public void run() {

                        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/jobsonthego/jobs/gps.php?latitude=" + latitude +"&longitude=" + longitude;
                        //String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/gps.php";
                        try {
                            HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                            Client.execute(httpget);
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex) {
                            String fail = "Fail!";
                            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),fail,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: maybe it's because it don't found 10.0.2.2? in emulator it's local but with device it's a bit different

Comment: Do you have your laptop set up to accept HTTP requests?

Comment: sorry am beginner to android. how to set up to accept HTTP requests in laptop?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Apache Tomcat in your eclipse available in laptop.
2. Window --> Show View --> Servers
3. In Servers Tab, Right Click --> New Server
4. Select the server version and configure the server.
5. Add the dynamic web project to your server and start the server.

If your server's  HTTP port is `8080` and your machine's IP Address is `172.25.5.25` and if the application URL is say `hudson/firstApplication`  and if the Web-Service path is `getUserName`,

Then configure in your mobile app to hit the following URL:

`http://172.25.5.25:8080/hudson/firstApplication/getUserName`